# XJC generate java files in several packages (directories) from one schema

Tags: jaxb, xjc

I have one schema file that I'm using to generate java files.
I want to specify in the schema file different packages to certain ComplexTypes. 
For example: All the Buttons java files should be inside a buttons package.

How do I do it? I'm using xjc ant task. Thank you.

Further details:

commons.xsd define, Foo, Bar, ButtonA, ButtonB

I want to folder (package) definition will be like that:

root

- Foo (File)
- Bar (File)
- buttons (Folder)
- - ButtonA (File)
- - ButtonB (File)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it is not possible with current JAXB implementation. Packages are quite strictly associated with namespaces, so it is unlikely that you could put classes from one schema into different packages.